# No such filter '"split': ffplay with ffmpeg in Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffplay

I am trying to visualize the YUV histograms of video overlayed with the video using ffmpeg on Python. The code that I use is the following:

```
subprocess.call(['ffplay','video.mp4','-vf','"split=2[a][b],[b]histogram,format=yuva444p[hh],[a][hh]overlay"'])
```

But when I execute the code, this error shows up:

[image]

It is a bit strange because if run the same line on the command window, it works with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double quotes around the filter - `subprocess.call` automatically adds quotes around arguments with special characters like `[`, `]`, `=`.

The following command should work:

```
subprocess.call(['ffplay','video.mp4','-vf','split=2[a][b],[b]histogram,format=yuva444p[hh],[a][hh]overlay'])
```

---

For watching the actual command line, you may add `-report` argument, and check the log file.

- `subprocess.call(['ffplay','video.mp4','-vf','split=2[a][b],[b]histogram,format=yuva444p[hh],[a][hh]overlay', '-report'])`
  Applies:
  `ffplay video.mp4 -vf "split=2[a][b],[b]histogram,format=yuva444p[hh],[a][hh]overlay" -report`.
  The above command is in correct syntax.
- `subprocess.call(['ffplay','video.mp4','-vf','"split=2[a][b],[b]histogram,format=yuva444p[hh],[a][hh]overlay"', '-report']`
  Applies:
  `ffplay video.mp4 -vf "\"split=2[a][b],[b]histogram,format=yuva444p[hh],[a][hh]overlay\"" -report`
  As you can see, subprocess added extra `"\` and `\"`, and this is the cause for your error.